# I did not understand why this for loop end with 1. why not 0 or -1 or something else

Tags: c, for-loop

I think it would be an infinite loop because the value of i is decremented. but the loop stops when it returns 1. why?

```
        int i ;
        for (i = 5; i; i--){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `i;` as a condition checks if `i` is non-zero. After `i` finishes the loop as 1, i decrements and then `i` becomes 0, so the loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the for loop syntax

```
for (initializationStatement; testExpression; updateStatement)
{
    // statements inside the body of loop
}
```

The second part is a `testExpression`. You testExpression is to test whether `i` is true(non-zero) or false(zero.)

After `1` is printed (i==1) and the loop back to the start point with `updateStatement` (i--) , i is set to 0. Your `testExpression` is 0 which is viewed as false. So the loop exists immediately. ( 0 will not be printed either.)

If you want your codes to be an loop to print i infinitely, you can leave the  `testExpression` empty.

Answer (score 2):

In C, any nonzero integer or non-null pointer used in a conditional evaluates to true, and any zero value or null pointer evaluates to false. So, for example:

```
if (5) {
    printf("This always executes.\n");
}
if (0) {
    printf("You will never see this.\n");
}
```

In your case, the loop is

```
for (i = 5; i; i--) {
    /* ... */
}
```

The loop condition is `i`, which means "loop while `i` is not zero, and stop once `i` becomes zero." As a result, once `i` drops to zero, the loop stops running. That means the last time you'll see the loop run is when `i = 1`, since after that it drops to zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parts to a for loop:

1. The initialisation (executed before the first iteration of the loop), in your example `i = 5`
2. The condition (executed before each iteration of the loop), in your example `i`
3. The final expression (executed after each iteration of the loop), in your example `i--`

In most for loops you'll find that the condition is a comparison, e.g. `i > 0`, however in your example the condition is a value of `0`.

In most languages `0` is considered as `false`, so it would stop the execution of the for loop once it reaches that number.